# How to guess or determine a SQL identity field and avoid duplicate

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc, distinct

I am trying to avoid duplicate updates to data, so I would like to know if there is a way to update only one row field without updating a piece of data in the subsequent row. So here it is the scenario, I have this code:

```
String sql = "update VAGAS set Matricula ='" +txtMat.getText()
    + "'  where Curso ='" +combocurso.getSelectedItem().toString()
    + "' AND Turma='"+turmacombo.getSelectedItem().toString()+"'";
pstmt = conLogin.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmt.execute();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Vagas atualizados com sucesso!");
```

I want to update the field `Matricula` (which means a student subscription ID), where course (`Curso`) equals the `combocurso.getSelectedItem().toString()` combobox and where `turma` (which means a Course classroom already filled group) equals the `combocurso.getSelectedItem().toString()` combobox.

Everything updates ok except for one issue, for example I have `Matricula` rows with the same name (`1ACC`) which represents 2 classroom vacancies. When I call the update it will fill both of them with a `Matricula` number which is not desired since i want to fill only one vacancy, but as they both have the same names it will fill both.

So there is a first field(column) named `Vagas` (not the table name but a column name) which is an `int identity (1,1)` field, and I want to fill only one field when I call the update command. I was trying to do that by comparing with the `Vagas` column but I cant seem to find a way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple records that meet your criteria, and you only want one of those records to be updated, you clearly have insufficient criteria for the Update. This isn't a code problem, it's a design problem... you need to choose how you wish to pick the one record to update out of the many records you are currently selecting. So how do you want to pick the record to update?

If your answer is that it really doesn't matter, you could use an aggregate function on the identity column as a constraint, for example:

```
WHERE ... AND Vagas = (SELECT MIN(Vagas) FROM VAGAS WHERE ...)
```

Note the "..." represents the conditions you're already using. My snippet of code just picks the VAGAS record with the lowest Vagas value (via the select subquery).

Comment: yes my answer would be the first record to update so it doesnt matter, i will try the piece of code you just posted and by the way , thanks you so much for the reply, that really means a lot to me, since people usually dont like to answer to newbie threads!
i ll be back with the asnwer if the desired result was achieved!!
Thanks a lot again!
kind regards,

EDIT: btw what comes after the WHERE ... ?
It might sound stupid but im still takin the baby steps hehe regarding sql

Comment: Nevermind about the last question i made when i put EDIT:...
and im just just here to say it worked the way i wanted , i mean what you just posted is all i needed and spent the whole day trying to use the Distinct command and some others..WOW thanks for hookin me up man i really appreciated!!
Kind regards,
Romulo Romero